# Freebase + GoogleAPI query returns errors when query results are over a certain amount

Tags: python, json, google-api, freebase

I'm trying to query all US counties and their goelocation (longitude + latitude) on Freebase. I've noticed that sometimes the query will work, but on other tries it returns the following: <"HttpError 503 when requesting...returned "Backend Error">.

I've tried changing the query result limits, and what I've found is that the limit at which my query breaks down varies; sometimes it works when "limit":2900, and sometimes it returns the above-mentioned error at "limit":1200.

Here's the code I've written so far:

```
    from itertools import islice

    from apiclient import discovery
    from apiclient import model
    import json
    from CREDENTIALS import FREEBASE_KEY

    from pandas import DataFrame, Series

    DEVELOPER_KEY = FREEBASE_KEY

    model.JsonModel.alt_param = ""
    freebase = discovery.build('freebase', 'v1', developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

    query_json = """
    [{
      "id": null,
      "name": null,
      "/location/us_county/fips_6_4_code": [],
      "/location/location/geolocation": {
        "latitude": null,
        "longitude": null
      },
      "limit": 3050
    }]""".replace("\n", " ")

    query = json.loads(query_json)

    response = json.loads(freebase.mqlread(query=json.dumps(query)).execute())

    results = list()

    for result in islice(response['result'], None):
        results.append( {'id': result['id'],
                         'name': result['name'],
                         'latitude': float(result['/location/location/geolocation']['latitude']),
                         'longitude': float(result['/location/location/geolocation']['longitude']),
                         'fips': result['/location/us_county/fips_6_4_code'],
                         } )

    states = DataFrame(results)
    plt.scatter(states["longitude"], states["latitude"])
```

It doesn't seem like a quota issue, and others have noted a similar issue on the Freebase mailing list: http://lists.freebase.com/pipermail/freebase-discuss/2011-December/007710.html
But this was for another type of data, so it seems like their solution isn't applicable to what I'm working on.

---

[EDIT]
I used a cursor to iterate through the data, and it work fine. Here's the final code I used:

```
    from itertools import islice
    from apiclient import discovery
    from apiclient import model
    import json
    from CREDENTIALS import FREEBASE_KEY
    from pandas import DataFrame, Series

    DEVELOPER_KEY = FREEBASE_KEY

    model.JsonModel.alt_param = ""
    freebase = discovery.build('freebase', 'v1', developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)
    query = [{
      "id": None,
      "name": None,
      "type": "/location/us_county",
      "/location/location/geolocation": {
        "latitude": None,
        "longitude": None
      }
    }]

    results = []
    count = 0
    def do_query(cursor=""):
        response = json.loads(freebase.mqlread(query=json.dumps(query), cursor=cursor).execute())
        for result in islice(response['result'], None):

            results.append( {'id': result['id'],
                             'name': result['name'],
                             'latitude': result['/location/location/geolocation']['latitude'],
                             'longitude': result['/location/location/geolocation']['longitude'],
                             } )
        return response.get("cursor")

    cursor = do_query()
    while(cursor):
        cursor = do_query(cursor)
        # Check how many iterations this loop has gone through.
        #print count
        count+=1

    # Plug results into a pandas DataFrame and plot.
    states = DataFrame(results)
    plt.scatter(states["longitude"], states["latitude"])
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a relatively simple query, but to put it in perspective the default limit is 100, which is a LOT lower than what you're asking for.  I'd suggest using a lower limit and a cursor to page through the results (and filing a bug report because it shouldn't be returning a generic "backend error" but some kind of MQL specific error)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some sample code to show you how to iterate through the results with a cursor:

```
cursor = ''
while cursor != False:
  response = json.loads(freebase.mqlread(query=json.dumps(query), cursor=cursor).execute())
  for county in response['result']:
    print county['name']
  cursor = response['cursor']
```

Just leave the `limit` clause out of your query and it will iterate through the whole list of counties in batches of 100 results.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I used a cursor and voila!, everything went accordingly.